# Make a tune-able resonant frequency

Tags: frequency, resonant

Using a long cable to a LC circuit reduced the resonant frequency, I reduced the inductance in order to increase the frequency; it worked. However the voltage amplitude decreased significantly. How can I find the balance between these two? How can I add a small circuit to make the frequency tune-able?

[image: circuit]

Comment: What is the source resistance?

Answer (score 2):

> *how can i add a small circuit to make the frequency tune-able?*

I would reduce C2, C3, C5 and C6 to accommodate the added capacitance of the cable. Cable is very roughly 100 pF per metre FYI.

> *However the voltage amplitude decreased significantly*

That's likely because the Q-factor of the circuit changed due to the increased capacitance and the decreased inductance.

You should be able to keep the resonant frequency the same using this method BUT, it only applies if the wavelength of the resonant frequency is many times greater than the added delay imposed by the cable.

If it isn't many times greater than the cable delay then, the cable will present an impedance to the left hand side driver circuit that can be significantly different to the right hand resonant load. Worst case scenario will be a cable electrical length that corresponds with a quarter wavelength of the resonant frequency.

So, depending on your operating frequency, several factors can be at play here.

Comment: Never seems to be the issue, the delay between the input signal and output signals is 30ns, where the resonant frequency is 650kHz (1350 ns). Thus, the delay is much smaller.  Also, the cable length is much smaller than the quarter wavelength of the resonant frequency

Comment: neither seems to*

Comment: Please explain what you mean.

Comment: I measured the delay imposed by the long cable and compared it to the wavelength of the resonant frequency (the wavelength of the resonant frequency is much greater than the delay).

Comment: Oh OK your 2nd comment was telling me to read "neither"!! OK that's good it's down to added cable capacitance.

Comment: How can I compensate for the cable capacitance ( increase the resonant frequency ) without compromising the voltage amplitude. Keep in mind that i tried different values for the inductance and capacitance yet I can’t find the right balance ( around 2Mhz and 200Vp-p)

Comment: I would use a simulator and model the circuit. I think you are at that stage at the moment.